# Sizing ButtonCells in NSMatrix

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to implement a Radiogroup with cocoa and used the example provided by apple [Using Radio Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/RadioButtons.html)

The following screenshot shows the problem I have. Even if the NSMatrix containing the cells have a NSRect large enough the cells themselves are not wide enough to display the titles.

How can I correct this?

[image]

---

```
NSButtonCell *prototype = [[[NSButtonCell alloc] init]autorelease];
[prototype setButtonType:NSRadioButton];

[prototype setBordered:YES];//only for testing

_view = [[[NSMatrix alloc] initWithFrame:rect
                                    mode:NSRadioModeMatrix
                               prototype:(NSCell *)prototype
                            numberOfRows:3
                         numberOfColumns:1]autorelease];

NSArray *cellArray = [_view cells];
for (std::size_t index = 0; index < 3; ++index)
{
    [[cellArray objectAtIndex:index] setTitle:@"a title"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setCellSize of matrix.

```
NSSize size = [_view cellSize];
size.width = 400;
[_view setCellSize:size];
```